# Are there infinitely many karmic numbers, i.e numbers whose primality radii equal one or a prime power?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbach-type-problems

For $n$ a large enough positive composite integer, say $r$ is a primality radius of $n$ if both $n-r$ and $n+r$ are prime. Say $n$ is a karmic number if the following holds: $r$ is a primality radius of $n$ implies $r=1$ or $\Lambda(r)\neq 0$ where $\Lambda$ is the von Mangoldt function.

Are there infinitely many karmic numbers?

Comment: You are asking if there are infinitely many pairs of primes $(p_1,p_2)$ such that either $p_2=p_1+2$ or $p_2=p_1+2q^k$ for some prime $q$ and integer $k$. There is no need to introduce either a "primality radius" nor a "karmic number".

Comment: Introducing such a terminology may help lead to further investigations in the future and also allows the formulation to be less dry. Math is not only a matter of reasoning but also of sensitivity. But indeed your reformulation is correct.

Comment: I disagree with your assessment. Adding unecessary terminology or hypotheses is very un-mathematical. The formulation isn't dry, it just requires to understand the object at hand by looking at examples and related theorems to patiently build a mental picture.

Comment: @ThomasSauvaget: I do not think your formulation is equivalent to OP's. For your pair, the number (p_1+p_2)/2$ may have another radii which fail to be of the required form.

Comment: Good point, Ilya. It must be a matter of quantifiers, as it seems Thomas used "exists" while I meant "for all".

Comment: I didn't understand the reason for the condition that $n$ is composite, or that it is "sufficiently large."  Also, what have you done so far?

Comment: I asked several questions related to the notion of primality radius on the assumption of Goldbach's conjecture, which is equivalent to the existence of a primality radius for all integer greater than $1$. A prime has trivially a primality radius equal to 0, so I discard this possibility as uninteresting.

Comment: If I haven't made a mistake, the only karmic numbers $< 10^5$ are
$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, 30, 34, 36, 42, 60$.  The sequence does not appear to be in the OEIS.  I would guess that these are the only karmic numbers, but a proof would be difficult.

Comment: Thank you Robert. The numbers $1$, $2$, $3$, $5$ and $7$ have to removed from the list though, as $1$ has no primality radius, while the four other integers are prime and thus admit $0$ as a primality radius, which is neither equal to $1$ nor to a prime power.

Comment: To be clear about  the logic of the comment from @ThomasSauvaget :  The OP asks if there are infinitely many $q$ such that for all $r$, $A(q,r)$ implies either $B(r)$ or $C(r)$.  The comment claims this is equivalent to asking  if there are infinitely many $q$ such that there exists an $r$ satisfying both $A(q,r)$ and either $B(r)$ or $C(r)$.  It isn't.

Comment: I may have an idea that might lead to a proof later: let $(r(i))_{1\leq i\leq n}$ be a strictly increasing arithmetic progression of positive integers. One may try to show that in any dense enough subsequence thereof, for example whose number of terms is $\Omega(n^{1-\delta})$ for some $0<\delta<1$, the arithmetic function $\omega$ takes at least 3 different values provided $n$ is large enough.

Comment: I can confirm that the non-primes up to 20 together with 24, 30, 34, 36, 42, and 60 are the only examples up to $10^8$.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel. I found an article about the prime factors in an arithmetic progression that should lead to a proof that there are finitely many karmic numbers divisible by 6. I'll try to post it as a partial answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here comes an attempt of proof of the statement I made in my last comment above.

So, the considered article is "PRIME FACTORS OF ARITHMETIC PROGRESSIONS AND
BINOMIAL COEFFICIENTS
T. N. SHOREY AND R. TIJDEMAN". In section 2.2, it is written that $\omega(\Delta)\geq\pi(2k)-1$, where $\Delta:=\Delta(x,d,k):=x(x+d)...(x+(k-1)d)$ with the hypotheses $x\geq 1$, $k>2$, $d>1$ and $gcd(x,d)=1$.

So let $n$ be a karmic number divisible by $6$. The primality radii of $n$ are all of the form $6n+1$ or $6n+5$. An arithmetic progression of such primality radii $r_1, r_2, r_3,\cdots r_k$ of length $k$ fulfills the aforementioned hypotheses and thus $\omega(r_{1}r_{2}r_{3}\cdots r_{k})\geq\pi(2\times k)-1\gg\frac{k}{\log k}$. But the total number of primality radii of $n$ is $\ll\left(\prod_{p\mid n, p>2}\frac{p-1}{p-2}\right)\frac{n}{\log^2 n}=o(\frac{n}{\log n})$ so there exists $C.n< k_{0}<n$ with $0<C<1$ such that $k>k_{0}$ implies at least one of the $r_{i}$ with $1\leq i\leq k$ fulfills $\omega(r_{i})>1$. Hence $r_{i}$ is neither $1$ nor a prime power, in contradiction with the fact that $n$ is a karmic number beyond some threshold.

Thus there are only finitely many karmic numbers divisible by $6$.

Comment: This only proves that in the sequence of primality radii of $n$ the lengths of arithmetic progressions are bounded, no? How do you conclude there are finitely many such numbers?

Comment: $n$ being a karmic number, it implies the number of primality radii of $n$ with $\omega(n)\leq 1$ is the total number of primality radii of $n$ which is an $o(\pi(n))$. But doesn't Green-Tao's theorem imply that the length of some arithmetic progression of primality radii of an integer $n$ as $n$ tends to infinity is unbounded?

Comment: Indeed, Green-Tao implies that infinitely many $n$ will have long arithmetic progressions in their primality radii. But those $n$ will be sporadic, and most likely won't cover all (sufficiently large) multiples of $6$. So you can't deduce from this the claim that large multiples of $6$ won't be sporadic.

Comment: Doesn't it follow from Dirichlet's theorem that those $n$ are equally distributed among the residual classes modulo $6$ which are not equal to the classes of $1$ or $5$?

Comment: Which $n$? And how does this follow from Dirichlet's theorem? Didn't we assume $n$ is divisible by $6$?

Comment: The $n$ from your previous comment, i.e the infinitely many ones that have long arithmetic progressions in their primality radii.

Comment: I don't see how Dirichlet's theorem guarantees this, nor how this is relevant for the problem at hand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101485/discussion-between-sylvain-julien-and-wojowu).